# Where do you put metaprogramming in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, metaprogramming

Lets say I want to add a few methods to ActionView::Helpers::FormBuilder like the examples in this blog http://blog.lrdesign.com/tag/adding-methods/  The methods are specific to this project and don't belong in a gem.

I've seen metaprogramming jammed into all kinds of places from the application.rb to after controller classes.  I want the next programmer ( or myself in 6 months ) to not be pulling their hair out wondering where these new methods came from.  Or why the text_field method is not working the way you expect it to.

What is the best place, file structure, and name spacing for these methods so Rails can load them up and the next rails programmers can understand what's going on.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare modules inside /lib/ and require them in application.rb.